# Chrome Extensions: Script (Gapi) not loading properly in React app bundled by Webpack, how to fix?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, webpack, google-api-js-client

As of today, when I attempt to import Gapi in a React App bundled by Webpack and compiled by Babel, I am thrown a `net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME` error. The error also indicates that my browser is trying to fetch about:blank when loading Gapi. I believe network requests indicates that these calls are being attempted by loaded Gapi scripts:

[Requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFmjI.png)

I've tried working around the issue with several React loader libraries and manually adding the Gapi script tag to head. I now believe this is primarily an issue with my configuration of Webpack. I am able to import Gapi without any problems in a plain html doc that I open in my browser. I had been able to use Gapi comfortably with Webpack prior to today.

Minimum reproducible example:

```
export type ReactGapiProps = {}

export const ReactGapi : FC<ReactGapiProps>  = () =>{

   const [tick, forceUpdate] = useReducer(x=>x+1, 0);


   const script = document.createElement("script");
   script.src = "https://apis.google.com/js/client.js";
   script.onload = ( e : Event)=>{
       if(script.onload){
           script.onload(e)
       }
       forceUpdate()
   }
   document.head.appendChild(script);

   return (

       <div>
           {window.gapi ? "Yay it worked!" : "Check the logs."}
       </div>

   )

}
```

Webpack config is CRA [default](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js).

**Update 1:**
It looks like some Chrome extensions are not playing nicely with Gapi. I can use the API just fine on Firefox and Chrome on other machines. Here's what I have it narrowed down to:

Pop up blocker for Chrome™ - Poper Blocker
Read and change all your data on the websites you visit

AdBlock — best ad blocker
Read and change all your data on the websites you visit

Okta Browser Plugin
Read and change all your data on the websites you visit

SendSafely Encryption for Chrome and Gmail
Read and change your data on all sendsafely-au.com sites and all sendsafely.com sites

LastPass: Free Password Manager
Read and change all your data on the websites you visit

Phish Alert
Read and change your data on a number of websites

Disconnect
Read and change all your data on the websites you visit

Update 2: I have not been able to replicate this error since the day I first encountered it. I'm going to try loading some of the extensions in Cypress today.